# Lippmann-Schwinger Equation (Numerical Method)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, software

I recently tried to code up the numerical solution for solving the LS equation, which is based on the "scatt.py" code from R.H. Landau's "Computational Physics".
The formulation is kind of like:
$$
R_{ij}=V_{ij}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{l=1}^N\frac{Mp_l^2V_{il}R_{lj}w_l}{p_E^2-p_l^2}-\frac{2}{\pi}(\sum_{l=1}^N\frac{w_l}{p_E^2-p_l^2})Mp^2_EV_{i,N+1}R_{N+1,j}
$$
where R, V are casted onto (N+1)x(N+1) Gaussian mesh of momenta where $p_{N+1}=p_E$ is the on-shell point, i.e., $p_E\rightarrow 0$(in code, it's set to 0.01).
Or it could rewritten as:
$$
R_{ij}=V_{ij}+\sum_{l}^{N+1}V_{il}D_lR_{lj}
$$
where
$$
D_{i}=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}{\frac{2}{\pi} \frac{M w_{i} p_{2}^{2}}{p_{E}^{2}-p_{i}^{2}}} & {i=1, N} \\ {-\frac{2}{\pi}\left(\sum_{l}^{N} \frac{w_{l}}{p_{E}^{2}-p_{l}^{2}}\right) Mp_{E}^{2}} & {i=N+1}\end{array}\right.
$$
So by rearranging the equation above, one gets:
$$
R_{ij}-\sum_{l}^{N+1}V_{il}D_lR_{lj}=V_{ij}\\
\sum_{l=1}^{N+1}(\delta_{il}-V_{il}D_l)R_{lj}=V_{ij}\\
\sum_{l=1}^{N+1}F_{il}R_{lj}=V_{ij}
$$
or $FR=V$, so $R=F^{-1}V$ will be solved. Then the matrix element $r_{00}=R(N+1,N+1)$ is used to compute the scattering length.

Ok, this is my first part, and it's done relatively perfectly. However, when it extends to a mix-channel case, or in formulation by "Computational physics" by K. Langanke:
$$
\sum_{l''}^{0,1}\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}(\delta_{ik}\delta_{l'l''}-V^{l'l''}_{ik}D_k)R_{kj}^{l''l}=V^{l'l}_{ij}
$$
and again $R=F^{-1}V$ where $F^{l'l''}_{ik}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{l'l''}-V^{l'l''}_{ik}D_k$ and all three matrices become size (2N+2)x(2N+2), or:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}{F^{l^{\prime}=0, l^{\prime \prime}=0}\left(p_{i}, p_{k}\right)} & {F^{l^{\prime}=0, l^{\prime \prime}=1}\left(p_{i}, p_{k}\right)} \\ {F^{l^{\prime}=1, l^{\prime \prime}=0}\left(p_{i}, p_{k}\right)} & {F^{l^{\prime}=1, l^{\prime \prime}=1}\left(p_{i}, p_{k}\right)}\end{array}\right)
$$
so we can get $R$ like:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ll}{r_{00}=R_{N+1, N+1}^{00}} & {r_{01}=R_{N+1,2 N+2}^{01}} \\ {r_{10}=R_{2 N+2, N+1}^{10}} & {r_{11}=R_{2 N+2,2 N+2}^{11}}\end{array}\right)
$$
then one can these matrix elements to compute the scattering length again
$$
\tan 2 \epsilon =\frac{2 r_{01}}{r_{00}-r_{11}} \\ 
\tan \delta_1 =-\mu p_{E}\left(r_{00}+r_{11}+\frac{r_{00}-r_{11}}{\cos 2 \epsilon}\right) \\ 
\tan \delta_2 =-\mu p_{E}\left(r_{00}+r_{11}-\frac{r_{00}-r_{11}}{\cos 2 \epsilon}\right)\\
a_{1}=\lim _{p_{E} \rightarrow 0}\left[-\frac{\tan \delta_1}{p_{E}}=\mu\left(r_{00}+r_{11}+\frac{r_{00}-r_{11}}{\cos 2 \epsilon}\right)\right]
$$
where $\mu=M/2$.

The problem is, the computed scattering length could be tuned with a parameter involved in the calculation of the potential (that's actually what my goal is, get that value of parameter by tuning), but the corresponding phase shifts are wrong, neither the mixing parameters.

Anyone has similar experience how to debug it?

I can share my written Mathematica notebook if is needed.

Comment: Never mind, the problem is solved. I had a misunderstanding of the calculation of the potential...

Comment: I am learning this topic. the question confuses me is that how does the matrix form of R avoid the  singular point if we set $p_E = p_l$, where $p_l$ is one of the integration points.